# CRUD between two Sharepoint farm

Tags: 2013, development, web-part, sharepoint-farm, multiple-farms

Please give advice for this case. I have two separated SharePoint sites:

- The first site is in one SharePoint farm. On this site we contain the private data and we use this site as the internal site. So we don't publish from this server.
- The second site is in another SharePoint farm. We use this site to display some customers' information. The data is collected from the first site. This is the public site.

My question is:

- I'd like the end-user of the first site to be able to create the second site's user. I've built the farm solution, but I'm confused about how this will affect the site in the second farm?
- How can the second site get data from the first one?